# Is there a way to insert a multidimensional associative array into an SQL table

Tags: php

i'm new to PHP and I want to migrate an array into a table and retrieve the contents of the table as an array that is identical to the array I am inserting into the table. This is my array

```
$productArr = ["ac" => ["001" => ["dimension"=>"H: 85 W: 67 D: 72",  "price"=>850.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "002" => ["dimension"=>"H: -- W: -- D: --",  "price"=>860.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "003" => ["dimension"=>"H: 95 W: 71 D: 90",  "price"=>890.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "004" => ["dimension"=>"H: 78 W: 68 D: 78",  "price"=>740.00 , "images"=>4], 
    "sf" => ["001" => ["dimension"=>"H: 82 W: 126 D: 60", "price"=>1200.00, "images"=>6], 
                     "002" => ["dimension"=>"H: 79 W: 180 D: 86", "price"=>1880.00, "images"=>5], 
                     "003" => ["dimension"=>"H: 80 W: 180 D: 74", "price"=>1800.00, "images"=>3], 
                     "004" => ["dimension"=>"H: 78 W: 175 D: 78", "price"=>1750.00, "images"=>3],];
```

Comment: Please read [tour] and [mcve]. After that - edit your question

Comment: Have you Googled your question? There are many answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a bit complex code and extract array index by index and write the query. Actually it is a simple insert query. Only thing you have to do is extract data.